# Windows Application to listen for voice commands

Tags: c#, .net, voice-recognition, google-voice

we are looking to create a smart application for the PC, written in .net c# which will listen for voice commands.
For example, as with xbox, each command will be pre-fixed with a word to tell the application that we are talking to it..
ie "fred, Find me user 1234"
"fred, open web browser"
etc etc

Basically, when a command has been captured, we would like to perform some kind of task. 
ie "fred, Find me user 1234"
Fred will query our sql database and return user details on the screen,

we have tried to google for help, but not actually found any relevant site. 
If someone could point us into the correct direction, that would be great.

Comment: You need the Microsoft Speech API (SAPI).

Comment: Will this allow for always listening? Having a google for it now..